# Forgot to assign boot tag when doing fdisk

Tags: linux, fdisk

Yesterday I supposed to do resize Azure Linux VM by following article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2016/05/24/step-by-step-how-to-resize-a-linux-vm-os-disk-in-azure-arm/

But, unfortunately I missed step number 8 i.e >  " Type “a” and select partition 1 to mark the boot partition as active. Type “p” to to ensure all settings are correct:"

After reboot Linux VM, unable to connect SSH. Is there anyway to resolve this and assign booting tag?

Please help me.

Thanks,

Srinivas Dasari.

Comment: Can you boot the VM from a CD/DVD image? Then you could use a Live Linux system to fix your VM harddisk image. Otherwise the article suggested to create a backup before proceeding. You can restore from the backup and resize the disk with all steps again.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is about an Azure VM, things like "boot from a Linux Live CD or boot an installation media in rescue mode" may not be possible.

But if you have another working Azure VM (not necessarily a Linux one), you could use PowerShell commands to present this disk/resource group temporarily to that VM as a second disk. Then you could use any partitioning tools available in the working VM to mark the first partition as bootable. The next steps would be detaching the problem disk from the working VM and assigning it back to the original Linux VM, which should then be bootable normally.

And since the cloud way of thinking is basically to assume everything is disposable and automate as much as possible, just restoring from a backup and repeating the extension steps, or even recreating the VM from scratch are equally valid solutions, if you have a backup or a script for easy rebuilding of your VM at hand.